# Pyinstaller .exe not working on USB pen drive

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I have created a .exe file using Pyinstaller that works fine until I copy it to a pen dive, and then try and re-run it after the pen drive has been ejected and re-inserted. I get the errors shown below[image: First error shown][image: Second error shown][image: Thrid error shown][image: Forth error shown]

Does anybody have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Even more strange, when I zip the .exe and send via file transfer. Once downloaded and extracted it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

By zipping the file before copying it to the USB pen drive, it has allowed my to unzip and then run the .exe, after the pen drive has been removed and then re-inserted.

Comment: Although I done fully understand why this has worked